# Displaying date time as "00000000" when value is null

Tags: c#, datetime

I am writing a small Console App and am retrieving data from a database and need to display the datetime data as "00000000" when the value saved in the database is null.

I have tried this

```
string temp = v.CompetentDate != null ? v.CompetentDate : "00000000";
DateTime competentdate = DateTime.Parse(temp);
v.CompetentDate = competentdate.ToString("ddMMyyyy");
```

but get an exception stating `String was not recognised as a valid DateTime`

How can I achieve getting the value as '00000000' for in case the value from the database is null.

Comment: You should be saving it as null. Display what you like, but save it as null if it was null.

Comment: Well, "00000000" is not a *valid date* as the *complier says* to you; ` DateTime.Parse("00000000")` will always throw exception

Comment: Yes. You should be using the nullable datetime and check for IsNull. It should be UI option to display it as 0000000. In WPF you can use trigger like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [DateTime.TryParse Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like this:

```
DateTime temp;
v.CompetentDate = DateTime.TryParse(competentdate,out temp)?
                  temp.ToString("ddMMyyyy"):
                  "00000000";
```

Answer (score 3):

why do you convert string to datetime and then back to string? just set string value

```
v.CompetentDate = v.CompetentDate ?? "00000000";
```

Comment: I guess he wants to change the format to `ddMMyyyy`.

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime.MinValue.ToString("ddMMyyyy")`returns `01010001` not `00000000`. That's why you get that exception if you try `DateTime.Parse("00000000");`.

Instead you might want this (even if i would use `01010001` instead of `00000000`):

```
v.CompetentDate = v.CompetentDate != null 
    ? DateTime.Parse(v.CompetentDate).ToString("ddMMyyyy") 
    : "00000000";
```

As an aside, why don't you use `DateTime` for `CompetentDate`?

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
string temp = v.CompetentDate != null ? v.CompetentDate : "00000000";
 DateTime competentdate = DateTime.Parse(temp);
v.CompetentDate = competentdate.ToString("dd,mm,yyyy");
```

Comment: When `temp` will be `00000000`, `DateTime.Parse` still would throw `FormatException`.